# is_home() returns TRUE on page template

Tags: pages, templates, homepage, template-hierarchy

I'm wondering why my link: `http://localhost/?page_id=3433` returns TRUE on `is_home()` usage:

```
if(is_home()){
    var_dump(is_home());                            
    die('test');                            
}
```

It clearly has template-mycustomtemplate.php set under Pages > This Page in Admin Panel. Can anyone shed some light on that?

UPDATE: it returns TRUE in the loop but FALSE outside the loop. So, I can use workaround but nonetheless, it looks like a bug to me if it returns TRUE in the loop that is present in that template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that it isn't actually a bug. In the loop `is_home()` will refer to the currently looped object and not to the page that you accessed. In fact that's handy!